# Where to find documentation for submitting a cheap paid application?

Tags: software-center, application-submission

I can't seem to find a concise guide to application submission.

Are there any links or howtos that would be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to visit http://developer.ubuntu.com/ as it contains all the information you need for submitting stuff to the app store as well as packaging. If you know how to package already (and by that I mean packaging that would be accepted by Ubuntu), you might be able to just skip to this page  http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the link you are looking for:

[Ubuntu App Developer](http://developer.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: Thanks by the way.  I know it seems like a horribly noob questions, but my google-fu was just horribly weak in this case I think.

Comment: I just noticed the other answer beat you by a minute.  I just saw yours first b/c of the upvote.

Comment: No problem. When I was typing my reply, your question was still unanswered. We posted around the same time :)